# Performance cost of sending an email with PHP?

Tags: php, performance, email

Rich sites such as facebook send you an email for every event that takes place, notification, friend request and so on, I would like to know how costly is it for the web server to perform this action? that also 100s of time a day for active and popular users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the site do not send emails itself. It just redirects email to server MTA, which then saves it in it's queue and sends when it thinks best.

To answer your question we need the definition of "costly". To send an email you typically need to execute some DNS queries, connect to remote server, exchange data with it. Is it costly in your opinion?

Comment: I would define costly as an operation that takes over 100ms to execute, since I am currently on shared hosting, I need to consider the cost of such features =).

Comment: Then the cost of sending a single email heavily depends on the server the letter is sent to, the speed of your DNS server, DNS cache, network load etc etc etc

Comment: Ah i see so its quite variable, thanks for the info I will try to run some benchmarks of my own.

Comment: Also keep in mind that some hosts put a limit on the amount of emails that you can send out. media temple puts it at around 100 an hour and godaddy limits it to 250 a day. You can buy more though but then cost becomes a little more literal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea group destinatarys by BCC header to reduce the email server calls, if you is using an external SMTP that it's the slower phase.

PHP only uses one thread that means that next email will be send once the current mail was sent to the SMTP server. In Java for example you can send emails in a pool of threads at same time, and course, it's faster.